# How can I add a timestamp to the end of a cron job's output file name? 

Tags: shell, cron

I want to track each crontab output to separated file.
Normally, I use this as crontab entry:

```
1  *    * * *   root    php /mix/dostuff.php > /tmp/dostuff.txt
```

Now, I want to make it to write instead of `/tmp/dostuff.txt`, to `/tmp/dostuff-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-II-SS.txt`

I could get the date part, using this:

```
TIMESTAMP=`date +%Y-%m-%H\ %k:%M:%S`
```

Now, how do I stick this TIMESTAMP into output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crontabs are run in a different environment than the default shell, so you can use a small shell script under your home directory with something like this in it (we'll name it `script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
php /mix/dostuff.php > /tmp/dostuff-`date +%Y-%m-%H\ %k:%M:%S`.txt
exit
```

then change this scripts permissions to ensure it is executable, 755 should be fine. Then in your crontab:

```
1  *    * * *   root    /home/yourusername/script.sh
```

Comment: Beware `%Y-%m-%H` isn't the usual year-month-date combination - try `%Y-%m-%d` !

Answer (score 8):

```
1  *    * * *   root    php /mix/dostuff.php > "/tmp/dostuff-`date +\%Y-\%m-\%H\ \%k:\%M:\%S`.txt"
```

Simple as that.

Comment: wont work, crontabs aren't evaluated in the same environment as a default shell.

Comment: I don't see how this would be a problem here. The cron environment is sufficient for this command. Besides, it works, I just tested it myself.

Comment: cron parses the file, not `/bin/bash`, thats why.

Comment: crontab(5): "The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline  or  % character,  will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the crontab file." You can even write entire shell scripts in a crontab line if you want!

Comment: the space between date and + is very important, just for the next guy who comes along

Comment: `root    php /mix/dostuff.php > /tmp/dostuff-$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%H\ \%k:\%M:\%S).txt` worked for me. No double-quotes necessary for simple file names and `$()` instead of ugly backticks.

Answer (score 2):

On CentOS 6.6, I use

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/script.php > cron-job-log-$(date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S).txt
```

it will create a file every 10 min

```
cron-job-log-20150401124001.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like following one. It will work perfectly.

1 * * * * root /home/yourusername/script.sh > /var/log/foldername/output_filename_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\H%).log

By before create backup folder into the log path.